# Godot4, input is running twice when I right click and is giving 2 seperate answer

Tags: gdscript, godot4

I am making an RTS game in godot4 4.2.1 Stable, just for shiggles. I am right clicking to perform a raycast. When I start the game and I right click, I am getting a duplicate input and it is giving me 2 seperate answers. Here is the code I am working with and its output.

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Right_Click"):
    rayCast()
    if results.size() > 0 && ControlsMaster.selected_actors.size() > 0:
        print("RIGHT CLICKED at: ", round(results.position), "\n")
        ControlsMaster.mouse_pos_ref = round(results.position)
        ControlsMaster.formation("square", results)
        print("complete\n")
        results.clear()

func rayCast():
    var worldspace = get_world_3d().direct_space_state
    var from = project_ray_origin(mouse_POS)
    var to = project_position(mouse_POS, 1000)
    results = worldspace.intersect_ray(PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(from, to))
```

The raycast is coming from the mouse and projecting to the map perpendicular to the screen. The ouput that I get is the following. This output is coming from a single click.

```
selected_actors array contains: [UNIT_0001:<CharacterBody3D#36691772857>, UNIT_0011:<CharacterBody3D#38033950217>]

RIGHT CLICKED at: (-40, 8, -6)

lead_actor_position(-40.12659, 7.526592, -6.26702)
result position(-40.12659, 7.526592, -6.26702)
{ "Position_0": (-40.12659, 7.526592, -6.26702), "Position_1": (-45.12659, 0, -6.26702), "Position_2": (-35.12659, 0, -6.26702), "Position_3": (-40.12659, 0, -1.26702), "Position_4": (-40.12659, 0, -11.26702), "Position_5": (-45.12659, 0, -1.26702), "Position_6": (-35.12659, 0, -1.26702), "Position_7": (-45.12659, 0, -11.26702), "Position_8": (-35.12659, 0, -1.26702) }
complete

RIGHT CLICKED at: (-78, 0, -107)

lead_actor_position(-78.43892, 0, -106.6246)
result position(-78.43892, 0, -106.6246)
{ "Position_0": (-78.43892, 0, -106.6246), "Position_1": (-83.43892, 0, -106.6246), "Position_2": (-73.43892, 0, -106.6246), "Position_3": (-78.43892, 0, -101.6246), "Position_4": (-78.43892, 0, -111.6246), "Position_5": (-83.43892, 0, -101.6246), "Position_6": (-73.43892, 0, -101.6246), "Position_7": (-83.43892, 0, -111.6246), "Position_8": (-73.43892, 0, -101.6246) }
complete
```

Im not sure how to add the 2 scripts that would make up the context, I dont come here often. Sorry in advance.

I have tried changing it to a key press or press and hold and it still does the double output.

The closer the raycast is to the center of the camera, the more accurate it is. The farther it is from 0,0,0 the further the actor spawns from where I actually did the mouse press at.

I have also tried to condition it so that it would check a variable called was_mouse_pressed. If it was false, it would allow the click, if True, then it would not allow the click. When I did this, it would run through the code, set it to True and then run the code again with it being false at the start and then turning True again. Even though I never had a code line to reset the bool to false.

I really don't understand and might switch to Unreal for the project. Unity isn't an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your question to tell me when is this code snippet running:

```
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("Right_Click"):
    rayCast()
```

So I do not know if this might be in a method that is being called twice for some unknown reason.

---

Now, assuming you would have catched something like that. This is what comes to mind: there are two instances with this script in runtime, so they both do a raycast and they both get a result.  *You might be able to confirm if this is the case with `print(self)`.*

The code suggest the script is intended to be attached to a `Camera3D`. If there are multiple `Camera3D` in the scene that have this script attached but are placed at different positions, it makes sense that they get different results from their raycats.

Do you have multiple `Camera3D` in the scene with this this script attached? You might want to only do this in the `current` one.

Alternatively, you might write this code in a central place and use `get_viewport().get_camera_3d()` to get the current camera, and use it to do the projection for the raycast.

Comment: I did do as you suggested and did a print(self). It is showing 2 cameras but I only have 1 Camera3D. There is no other that exists or is created.

`self print: CameraMaster:<Camera3D#29293020374>
self print: Camera3D:<Camera3D#33738982639>`
sorry, not a lot of room to respond in detail, I simply don't know how to...

Comment: I have a central master script that handles that inherits from Camera3D and handles the controls and mouse input, my other master script is one that handles formations, Actor movement style, speed, formations, targeting, pathing etc.

Comment: @ericczimcharo wild guess of what could be: I have seen people add script to autoloads thinking that will guarantee there will be only one instance, but the result is that they will have two: one created by the autoload, and one added in a scene.

Comment: @ericczimcharo You can try `print(self.get_path())` that should tell you where on the scene tree they are.

Comment: I've done both sugestions and more confused on its outcome.

The outcome of me disabling the autoloaded camera_master.gd script and adding the `print(self.get_path())` is this...

self print: CameraMaster:<Camera3D#29293020374>
self path print: /root/CameraMaster

self print: Camera3D:<Camera3D#33738982639>
self path print: /root/GLOBAL_OBJECT/Camera3D

Then I reloaded the project and its output was only the Camera3D#3373...

Why was it running the script twice when it was autoloaded?

Comment: @ericczimcharo Adding the autoload makes Godot create an instance before loading the main scene (it does not prevent other instances from existing, i.e. the term "singleton" is wrong). I do not know why it didn't go away rightaway when disabling the autoload.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I only have time on the weekends to work on this and maybe an hour or 2 during the week. I was fighting with that issue for almost 2 hours and it was killing me. Thanks for the help! :)